# App engine query retrieve data with index reference

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

```
class Entry(Base):
    amount = db.IntegerProperty()


entries = Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0")
```

Is there a way to refer to entries result with an index as an array, for example

```
my_entry = entries[4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entries = [x for x in Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0")]`

The distinction between this and previous answers is that it filters at the datastore rather than in the handler, and doesn't require you to guess the maximum number of entities that will be returned.

Comment: you can simply use `list(Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0"))`.

Comment: Both are less efficient than simply calling `.fetch(n)` on the query, where n is the maximum number of results you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [fetch()](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch) method on the `Query` instance:

```
class Entry(Base):
    amount = db.IntegerProperty()


entries = Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0").fetch(5)

print entries[4].amount
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a fetch() . which will give you a list of entries . In that case my_entry=entries[4] will give you the fifth object. What you were trying to do is manipulating the gql object. Which obviously won't work. Try this

```
class Entry(Base):
    amount = db.IntegerProperty()


entries = Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0").fetch(1000)

print entries[4].amount
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to one object of specific index in your result query, you can use the `fetch` method of `db.Query` with `offset` parameter:

```
entry = Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0").fetch(1, offset=4)[0]
print entry.amount
```

However, if you want to refer to the multiple objects from the query results, `fetch` them all and index as normal Python array:

```
entries = Entry.gql("WHERE amount > 0").fetch(1000)
print entries[4].amount
print entries[5].amount
print entries[7].amount
# etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
entries= [entry for entry from Entry.all() if entry.amount > 0]
print entries[4]
```

Comment: This will return all records from the datastore and won't scale.